# Videos splitting using FFMpeg in android

Tags: android, android-ffmpeg

Hi i am using **FFMpeg** for splitting video(**39MB**) as 15 parts using below command and that's fine video is splitting and there is no damage.

But problem is actually my main file size is **39MB** but after splitting this video then splitting video files size become very large compare to main file

When i count splitting files size it was **69MB**

Can some one suggested me please.

**-i "input.mp4" -ss 00:00:01 -t 00:00:03 -acodec copy -vcodec copy "output.mp4"**

Comment: `below command`?

Comment: Can you check if the actual size/dimensions of the video changes after 'export'?

Comment: After recorded my main video i have checked that video size,It was 39MB,But when i splitting then all parts count was 69MB

Comment: No I mean the dimensions of the video not the file size.

Comment: you mean recorded video width and height?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I was not clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143685/discussion-between-krish-and-h-brooks).